# Form doesn't work with captcha

Tags: php, forms, session, captcha

I created form which sends an email. But when I use `$_SESSION['secure']` it doesn't work. Is it safe to just randomize 4-digit number?

**generate.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

    $text = $_SESSION['secure'];
    $font_size = 20;
    $img_width = 110;
    $img_height = 40;

    $img = imagecreate($img_width, $img_height);
    imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
    $txt_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);


    for($x = 1; $x <= 50; $x++){
        $x1 = rand(1, 100);
        $y1 = rand(1, 100);
        $x2 = rand(1, 100);
        $y2 = rand(1, 100);

        imageline($img, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $txt_color);
    }

    imagettftext($img, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $txt_color,  'NautilusPompiliusRegular.ttf', $text);
    imagejpeg($img);
?>
```

**contact.php**

```
    <?php
        session_start();

        $_SESSION['secure'] = rand(1000, 9999);
        $to = '***';/*Change it to the site owners email.*/
        $subject = 'New customer!';

        $contact_name = $_POST['contact_name'];
        $contact_email = $_POST['contact_email'];
        $contact_message = $_POST['contact_message'];
        $contact_captcha = $_POST['contact_captcha'];

        $headers = 'From: '. $contact_name . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: '. $contact_email . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        $result = "";
        if($_SESSION['secure'] === $contact_captcha){
            mail($to, $subject, $contact_message, $headers); 
            $result = "Your message was successfully sent.";
        }else{
            $result = "Error. Some field values are too long. Try again.";
        }
        echo '       
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">...'

   <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-2 control-div"><img src="generate.php" /></div>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_captcha" placeholder="Enter the value from the img." value="" maxlength="5" required>
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';
```

Note: I don't destroy_session(), generate.php is separate file (I start sessions in both). When I don't use if/else statement, it works.

Comment: Try again. session secure7393 contact captcha 3467. Now they are different.

Comment: Why don't you use a service like `recaptcha`? https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html

Comment: Because I don't understand it. It have to protect form from robots, but I think that if robots can put values in the fields then they can also input a simple value in the checkbox (just press on it).

Comment: then why not a system like http://solvemedia.com/publishers/captcha-type-in ?

Comment: I like how solvemedias captcha looks like and works, but here it have to be this captcha (looks good and simple if I forget about this problem with sessions).

Comment: Do anyone know, why I can't sent $contact_name which contains spaces and what should I do to allow it?

Comment: To should be formatted like this: `$contact_name <$contact_email>` and the `From` should be **your (support) email**.

Comment: I'd like to make a point about how you are writing your session variables. you shoul dbe using a key to make your sessions unique to your website, as you could easily overwrite or even read from a session supposed for another site. `$_SESSION[KEY]['sessionName'] = "foo";`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, first you should always check if you have a $_POST, because when you submit the post, you change the session value

So you code should look like

```
session_start();
if($_POST) {
    $to = '***';/*Change it to the site owners email.*/
    $subject = 'New customer!';

    $contact_name = $_POST['contact_name'];
    $contact_email = $_POST['contact_email'];
    $contact_message = $_POST['contact_message'];
    $contact_captcha = $_POST['contact_captcha'];

    $headers = 'From: '. $contact_name . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: '. $contact_email . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $result = "";
    if($_SESSION['secure'] === $contact_captcha){
        mail($to, $subject, $contact_message, $headers); 
        $result = "Your message was successfully sent.";
    }else{
        $_SESSION['secure'] = rand(1000, 9999); // Change capcha because it is wrong
        $result = "Error. Some field values are too long. Try again.";
    }
} else {
   $_SESSION['secure'] = rand(1000, 9999);
}
// Show the html after
```

Comment: I understood you. But your code doesn't change the result. Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't pasted all your html I am not 100% that you have wrapped your form in a `<form method="post" action="?">...</form>`.

@Martin Andreev is correct though you need to have a check for the $_POST param, otherwise it will remake the $_SESSION each time.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['contact_captcha']) && isset($_SESSION['secure'])) {
    $to = '***';/*Change it to the site owners email.*/
    $subject = 'New customer!';

    $contact_name = $_POST['contact_name'];
    $contact_email = $_POST['contact_email'];
    $contact_message = $_POST['contact_message'];
    $contact_captcha = $_POST['contact_captcha'];

    $headers = 'From: '. $contact_name . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: '. $contact_email . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $result = "";

    if($_SESSION['secure'] === $contact_captcha){
        mail($to, $subject, $contact_message, $headers); 
        $result = "Your message was successfully sent.";
    } else {
        $result = "Error. Some field values are too long. Try again."
    }
}

$_SESSION['secure'] = rand(1000, 9999);
//html
```

If your gettings no results, then var_dump() $_POST and $_SESSION if the session is blank you may need to look at your server settings and cookies on your browser.

EDIT: REMOVE THE === AND MAKE IT == it maybe a strict type issue:

```
if($_SESSION['secure'] == $contact_captcha){
```

When you var_dump both they need to have the same types to work with ===

i.e. $_POST['contact_captcha'] is a string? On var_dump() what are the types?

```
var_dump($_SESSION['secure']);
string(1) "1"

var_dump($contact_captcha);
int(1)
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['secure'] ` and `$contact_captcha` are equals, but after submit `$_SESSION['secure'] ` changes it's value, so form will never send.

Comment: `<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="contact.php">` what I've got.

Comment: If its changing it's value then you need to see how many times the contact.php file is called on the page, open the developer toolbar, and see how many calls are made to the contact.php file. You could also store the time of generation in the session i.e. $_SESSION['time'] = time(); and if the value is not the same you know it is called more than once.

Comment: In contact.php ones.

Comment: I recived 1456160935.